# How to select all records from one table that exactly match another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, matching

I have a tricky question about select: I have this table structure:

```
declare @one as table (serviceid int null)

declare @two as table (id int null, serviceid int null)

insert into @two 
values (15,195),(15,84),(16,195),(16,84),(16,NULL),(17,195),(17,84),(17,8)
```

I need get exactly matching **@two.ID** (that matches the serviceid and count intable @two )

**Scenario 1:**

```
insert into @one values (195),(84)
```

I need get only ID- **15**, because all serviceid is matching and record count in table @one is 2.

**Scenario2:**

```
Insert into @one values (195),(84),(8)
```

I need get only ID- 16 and 17, **17**: because all serviceid is matching and record count in table @one is 3. , **16** : because two services are matching,record count in table @one is 3 and `NULL` means 'Don't Matter'(whoever)

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid, that the answer you accepted is wrong (as you noticed in comment). Here is working query:

```
-- tables declaration ---------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @one as table (serviceid int null)
declare @two as table (id int null, serviceid int null)
-- values insert --------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into @two values (15,195),(15,84),(16,195),(16,84),(16,NULL),(17,195),(17,84),(17,8)
insert into @one values (195),(84)
-- actual query ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
select id from (
select id,
       --check, where we have null records in @one caused by null values in @two, which is acceptable (assifgned value when acceptable = 0)
       case when ([ONE].serviceid is not null and [TWO].serviceid is not null) or ([ONE].serviceid is null and [TWO].serviceid is null) then 0 else 1 end [IsMatched]
from (
    select *, COUNT(*) over (partition by id) as [idCount] from @two
) [TWO] left join (
    select serviceid, COUNT(*) over (partition by (select null)) [idCount] from @one
) [ONE] on ([TWO].idCount = [ONE].idCount and [TWO].serviceid = [ONE].serviceid)
) [a] group by id
having SUM(IsMatched) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I want ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @one as table (serviceid int null)

declare @two as table (id int null, serviceid int null)

insert into @two values (15,195),(15,84),(16,195),(16,84),(16,NULL),(17,195),(17,84),(17,8);
--insert into @one values (195),(84);
Insert into @one values (195),(84),(8)

select distinct t.id
from @two t
where exists (select * from @one o where t.serviceid = o.serviceid)
      and (select count(*) from @one) = (select count(*) from @two t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```

Comment: Nice idea. But in case `INSERT INTO @one
VALUES (195)
 ,(84)
 ,(7) ` i get 16 and 17, but only need to get 16

Comment: It means I didn't understand you well. Why don't you consider 17 as the answer if (17,195) gives you a match with @one and the count of 17 in two is 3 that equals to number of rowss in one?

Comment: @user3616309 Ok, I first thought that only the count should match while the services should too, I updated my answer and now I count only those that match.